# Element.querySelectorAll weird behaviour when query HTML element children

Tags: html, selectors-api

I encounter a weird behavior when using `querySelectorAll` to search children for an element.

we have the following HTML elements tree:

```html
<div class="channels-featured-section">
 <div class="yui3-video-coverage-item ">
  <span class="now-playing">NOW<br>PLAYING</span>
  <a href="#" class="yui3-video-coverage-item-trigger">
   <div>
   </div>
   <p></p>
   <div class="yui3-video-coverage-item ">
    <span class="now-playing">NOW<br>PLAYING</span>
    <a href="#" class="yui3-video-coverage-item-trigger">
     <div></div>
     <p>?</p>
    </a>
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

when taking the first DIV and make `element.queryAelectorAll("div div div div")` you suppose to get only the internal most DIV `<div class="yui3-video-coverage-item-img-wrap"></div>`, but actually it giving you all the DIV elements inside that small tree.

now making the query on the same element in the following way: `element.queryAelectorAll("div div div div div div div div div div")` giving the same result.

now, we don't have so many hierarchies of DOM elements.

it is so weird and I puzzled about it for hours.

Answer (score 0):

After me and my co-workers hitting our head on the wall about it, we found out the following fast:

`Element.prototype.querySelectorAll` query from the `document` level of DOM and filter all result which is **NOT** inside current element we are querying.

Meaning, the result is just like you query the DOM `docuemnt.querySelectorAll` and just filtered all elements which are not contained inside the root element you query from.

the reason we had that issue is that the DOM we queried is REACT and we had so many `div` elements and no class we can hang into.

We found [that article](https://johnresig.com/blog/thoughts-on-queryselectorall/) that explains it in great details. So please make sure you know that rule for the future.